# What determines when a road should be widened?

Tags: transportation, highway-engineering

I know this depends on a variety of factors including overall traffic volumes, peak traffic volumes, types of vehicles, and type of road, but how exactly do traffic engineers determine how many lanes a section of road should contain and when the number of lanes should be increased?

Comment: By considering the very factors you mention.

Comment: Sorry, but what I'm trying to figure out is at what point (eg. specific AADT, specific peak volume, etc.)

Comment: Include number of accidents in your list.

Answer (score 2):

The *Highway Capacity Manual* contains specific analysis methods for determining acceptable levels of service.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_service_(transportation)

Available funding and rights-of-way also determine the priority of improvements.